# How long to release an updated Debian?

Tags: ros, debian, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I released a package recently that had some errors ('pid' package v0.0.1). So I fixed the errors and made another pull request which was merged with ros:master. It was merged about two weeks ago. However, if I do 'sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pid', it still installs v0.0.1... the broken version. Have I done anything wrong or does it just take awhile to update the debians?

Some interesting tidbits... the build status page shows the right version (v0.0.3):
http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html

And I got an email recently about "Jenkins build is back to normal." Not sure what that's all about.
http://jenkins.ros.org/job/doc-indigo-pid/4/

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205725/how-long-to-release-an-updated-debian?/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your package is staged in the testing repo.

If you look at the debbuild status page you'll see the new version is in 2 of 3 of the repos. http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=pid

It's in the testing repository at the moment. Documented here: http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository

About every 2 weeks the packages are synced from ros-shadow-fixed to public. That is when the announcement will got out to ROS-users@ like [this](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2015-March/069248.html)

The 2 week timeline is nominal. Sometimes the cycle is longer, sometimes shorter. Issues relating to the release timeline should be discussed on [ros-release@](http://lists.ros.org/mailman/listinfo/ros-release)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1